# Preference onClick Not Detected

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

i have setup an onpreference click listener for a preference but it fails to fire even though the preference is found by the find preference command.

Activity

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Display the fragment as the main content
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        Context context;
        private final String DOB = "date";
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

            Preference dob = findPreference(DOB);
            Log.i("test", dob.getKey() + "");

            dob.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Log.i("test", "2");
                    return false;
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The preference xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="My Account">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="profile_name"
            android:summary="Taylor Swift"
            android:title="Username" />

        <Preference
            android:key="date"
            android:summary="N.A."
            android:title="@string/date" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The log output for "test" correctly displays the key of the preference but the log within the onclick never fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created simple project with your code and everything seems to be working fine.

```
Log.i("test", "2");
```

is being called when I click "Date" field.